# Laravel clean links without spaces or uppercase

Tags: laravel, url

I image this is a simple one. I have a url like '../area/England' and '../area/United%20States' that I want to be '../area/england' and '../area/united-states' respectively.

These areas are stored in my database as 'England' and 'United States'. I was thinking I could store them as the value I want which would be good for the urls ('england' and 'united-states'), but then I would have to convert them back to the original when I display them on the page (ex. 'Welcome to United States!'). So this option is not great as I will have to do conversion anyways.

So my questions are, 
1. What is the best practice to do this type of url manipulation? 
And 
2. Where do I put my code? (strtolower and str_replace)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "Customizing the resolution logic" section of https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

In your route:

```
Route::get('/area/{country}',function(Country $country){})
```

Then in your `RouteServiceProvider::boot` method, you can write a statement like this:

```
$router->bind('country', function ($value) {
  return Country::where('name', strtoupper(str_replace("-"," ",$value))->first();
});
```

However, converting a URL slug to a country name might not always work like this.  If you can't write a function that reliably converts a slug to a country name, then you should create a new database column called `slug` and then use:

```
$router->bind('country', function ($value) {
  return Country::where('slug', $value)->first();
});
```

I guess you could also pull the whole list of countries and sort through them, doing `str_replace` and `strtolower` until you find a match, caching the country results for awhile each time.  Less efficient though, I would make a slug column.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried changing the routes then adding what you've provided to RouteServiceProvider, and I'm still getting the wrong output. To be honest I don't know enough about RouteServiceProvider to use it on my own and debug why this isn't working.

Comment: If you `dd($value)` in the `$router->bind` function, you will see that it is receiving the URL segment `england` or `united-states`.  Then whatever returns from that function is what your function in `Route::get()` will receive.  You're just writing a function to convert a URL segment to a model.  If you post what you're seeing I may be able to help further.

Comment: Hi @Jeff. I'm thinking that maybe I didn't ask my question as clear as it could be and that's where the confusion is. With the above piece of code, my url is still '/area/England'. It seems like it is searching for a case insensitive match in the database, instead of making the url all lowercase, or with no spaces? Oh, and dd($value) outputs 'England'.

Comment: I think what you should do is create a column in your database called `slug`.  You can set that column to things like `england` or `united-states` using whatever string replacement functions you'd like.  Then use that last piece of code.  The reason you have to define the `slug` column is because there's no reliable way to convert `united-states` to `United States`, so you should define the slugs manually and then use that last piece of code.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I've added the slug columns and am now getting the correct urls. I couldn't quite get your $router->bind code to work correctly, so I'm doing this in my controller.         $country = Country::with('subarea')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('country.show', compact('country')); I know this isn't good practice and I still need to look into moving it out of the controller. Thanks again.