# Laravel Limit route parameter dynamically (but only show valid urls)

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, laravel-routing

I cannot wrap my mind around something.

I have a table which I render in my **tables.blade.php** file like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Country</th>
         <th scope="col">Member</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach ($members as $member)  
         @if ($member->continent == 'Europe')
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <a href="{{ route('country', $member->country) }}">{{ $member->country }}</a>
               </td>
               <td class="align-middle player-code copy-code">
                  {{ $member->name }}                   
               </td>
            </tr>
         @endif
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see you can click on a country which will show you members from one country in a new view (code not shown here).
The route for that single country site in the **web.php** looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{country}', 'PageController@show')->name('country');
```

Everything worked fine until I realized that I could put anything as `'country'` and still would get shown the site for the country just with an empty table.
So `'/abcde'` would get you the view with just a naked table.

So I changed the route like this:

```
Route::get('/{country}', 'PageController@show')->name('country')->where('country', ('United Kingdom|France|Belgium|South Africa);
//the list is much longer
```

Ok. So now I have constrained the `'country'`-parameter in a pretty static way. And I have the feeling that is not the way it should be done. Because in the end I would like to have URLS that look like this `'/united-kingdom'`, `'/france'`, but now they're looking like this `'/United%20Kingdom'`.
I saw the answers to this question [Laravel clean links without spaces or uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215662/laravel-clean-links-without-spaces-or-uppercase) , but for me they're not so useful since I'm not working with Eloquent models but the Query Builder (The db tables I get are ready made, I only have to display them).

So my questions are:

**How to limit a route parameter more dynamically?**

**How to display data one way (written like it's also in the table like this 'United Kingdom'), but have a route like this ('united-kingdom')?**

I am willing to provide more code or info if you need, I'm just pretty confused and have the feeling I'm overlooking something (big).

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: do your control in the controller function. if there is no country in the database, you return a error or a redirect

Comment: Do you have a model called Country ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI No, I'm using the Query Builder methods (since the database is not created by me).

Answer (score 0):

> If you would like a route parameter to always be constrained by a
>   given regular expression, you may use the pattern method. You should
>   define these patterns in the `boot` method of your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;    
//...

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{

    $list_of_countries = DB::table('members')->whereNotNull('country')->pluck("country")->unique()->map(function ($name) {
         return str_slug($name, '-');
    })->reject(function ($name) {
         return empty($name);
    })->toArray();

    $regex = '(' . implode('|', $list_of_countries) . ')';

    Route::pattern('{country-slug}', $regex);

    parent::boot();
}
```

routes\web.php

```
Route::get('/{country-slug}', 'PageController@show')->name('country');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-global-constraints)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm not using a Model.

Comment: @jamawe You may use the table method on the DB facade (DB::table('members')) instead of Model.

See updated answer